# Display webcam feed on windows form in C# without using 3rd party libraries

Tags: c#, winforms, webcam

Here's the thing. I like building my own libraries because I learn a LOT about the functionality of everything in doing so. I'm looking to build a viewport on my windows form application (in C#) that streams live feed from my webcam.

Anyone know how to do this? I've found countless tutorials using other peoples libraries, but like I said before that's not what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't use a 3rd party library?

Comment: It's not that I can't. I've successfully done it using 3rd party libraries, but I like to know the inner-workings and even if some of them supply the code it's so much of a maze to sort through, I'd rather find documentation that explains how to build it from the ground up, that explains why everything works how it works, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete tutorial on writing your own API : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/integrate-the-web-webcam-functionality-using-C-Sharp-net-and-com-part-viii/

Does not use a third party library but the windows built in one called avicap32.dll

Comment: Thanks!! That has a lot of depth. Not quite sure if it's exactly what I'm looking for because it's a lot to read, but Google may fill in the missing gaps.